# Vue.JS / JEST - Unable to Mock Asset Reference

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mocking, jestjs, vue-cli-3

I am trying to set up a component with a reference link to 3 assets. This is breaking all of my tests as follows...

> **Test suite failed to run**
>
> SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token.

The second of the following 4 reference lines are highlighted (the last 3 are images).

```
import SpecialistChooser from './specialist-chooser'

import imgCo2 from '@/assets/motivations/t-co2.jpg'
import imgFuelBill from '@/assets/motivations/fuel-bill.jpg'
import imgBoth from '@/assets/motivations/both.jpg'
```

I have read through a detailed article on mocking assets here...
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/webpack.html

But this doesn't seem to make any odds. Following that I have a general mock set up for files that looks like this...

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    process(src, filename) {
        return 'module.exports = ' + JSON.stringify(path.basename(filename)) + ';'
    },
}
```

(file-mock.js)

My jest config in my package.json is as follows...

```
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "vue"
    ],
    "transform": {
      ".*\\.(vue)$": "vue-jest",
      "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest"
    },
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1",
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/file-mock.js",
      "\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/style-mock.js"
    },
    "collectCoverage": false,
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,vue}",
      "!**/node_modules/**",
      "!**/dist/**"
    ]
  }
```

I'm not making any headway here and my googling keeps returning various different sites reprinting exactly the same article I've already linked to. I must be missing something but I can't see what!

I've tried manually mocking the references in the test file too, like this...

```
jest.mock('@/assets/motivations/t-co2.jpg', () => {
    return '/app/img/t-co2.jpg'
})
jest.mock('@/assets/motivations/fuel-bill.jpg', () => {
    return '/app/img/fuel-bill.jpg'
})
jest.mock('@/assets/motivations/both.jpg', () => {
    return '/app/img/both.jpg'
})
```

This doesn't work either.

**UPDATED: Working Configuration**
After fixing the initial problem, thanks to the answer below, I was able to put together a solid working implementation on this and thought I would share it for future searchers.

My `package.json` is now configured as follows...

```
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "vue"
    ],
    "transform": {
      ".*\\.(vue)$": "vue-jest",
      "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|webp|svg)$": "<rootDir>/img-test-transformer.js",
      "\\.(eot|otf|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$": "<rootDir>/font-test-transformer.js",
      "\\.(mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/media-test-transformer.js"
    },
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/style-mock.js",
      "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
    }
```

Instead of using the `moduleNameMapper` I am using `transform` (I was also trying to combine the two which didn't work in my original post). The `transform` option allows me to return useful things from the imports. For Vue, in the case of most file imports I simply want the path. In order to do this I wrote 3 transformers as follows...

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    process(src, filename) {
        return 'module.exports = ' + JSON.stringify('/app/img/' +path.basename(filename)) + ';'
    },
}

const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    process(src, filename) {
        return 'module.exports = ' + JSON.stringify('/app/fonts/' + path.basename(filename)) + ';'
    },
}

const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    process(src, filename) {
        return 'module.exports = ' + JSON.stringify('/app/media/' + path.basename(filename)) + ';'
    },
}
```

This gives me different return filename path types for use in my tests.

No `jest.mock` calls required anywhere either.

PS: **Beware Jest Cache** - This stung me badly and I had to run `jest --clearCache` a few times otherwise changes to the transformers aren't read.

Comment: Is the error on the `import` keyword? How are you running `jest`?

Comment: I'm guessing that you may need to re-order your `moduleNameMapper` array placing `"^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1",` last

Comment: @tony19 - The error is on the import statement when importing an image. I'm running jest via a vue-cli npm script.

Comment: @Teneff - That suggestion was the answer - I kind of felt this was a 'what am I not seeing here' problem... 

Please can you re-add this as an answer and I'll give you credit for it.

Comment: @KeithJackson upvote my comment, I want a Jest hat :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the current configuration the assets will be matched by the first regular expression and `"<rootDir>/src/$1"` would be used instead of the desired `<rootDir>/__mocks__/file-mock.js`

A solution would be re-ordering the `moduleNameMapper` as below

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
  "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/file-mock.js",
  "\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/style-mock.js",
  "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
},
```